# How to extract files from or examine an Android App Bundle

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

The Android App Bundle is a new format for packaging Android apps for distribution. It allows an app to be distributed for multiple architectures (such as ARM 32 and ARM 64 bit) in a single bundle. See [Google Developer Description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/).

Android Studio, through the miracle of gradle, builds these things if you want.

But... how can you see exactly what is inside? The standard tool, bundletool, doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: If you are trying to create a FAQ-style entry here, please have your question be the question, and please [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: This article goes into a lot of detail about app bundles: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-android-app-bundle-ca16846fa3d7

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR the Android App Bundle is a zip file, minus the .zip file extension.

It turns out that the bundle is just a zip file, with the wrong extension. I use a Mac for development, and by adding .zip to a copy of the bundle, I could then dig into it on finder by double-clicking it to unzip it. Any old unzip program would work as well, although you might or might not need to add the .zip extension.

My motivation for doing this? I just re-released my app using the bundle for the first time. I wanted to know what was in it - especially if it really had the architectures I hoped for. It does.

Bundletool will do things unzip won't - like build an apk file for the architecture you want, based on the bundle. Since that's useful for testing, I'll probably install the thing anyway, just in case. There is apparently no straightforward way to test an app that is ready for distribution in a bundle, except by extracting the apk(s) or, ugh, uploading it to the Play Store as a test distribution.

Bundletool is recommended for testing, and is described [here].[1](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool)

Comment: I'll add to this answer that Studio has a "Bundle Explorer" built in. When you build a Bundle, it prompts a notification which allows you to locate the file on disk, and to analyze the content.